# How to create a big TextureRegion from multiple small TextureRegions in Andengine?

Tags: android, textures, andengine, sprite

I am creating a 2D runner game with Andengine and my platforms are created from multiple 32x32 sprites that have different texture regions. I want to be able to create platforms with different sizes, so I can't create a platform from a single image file.

So each of my platforms are created from few sprites to several hundreds sprites if the platform is big. This obviously reduces the performances of my game. That's why I am trying to find a way to create a big TextureRegion from my small tiles that I use create my platforms, so I would be able to create less sprites.

I would like to be able to whether create a TextureRegion of a platform that does not always have the same size or to create a TextureRegion of the entire stage (made of multiple platforms).

How can I stick TextureRegions together in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understood the textureRegions, they are only some kind of reference on a given atlas (that contains the memorized image). increasing the size of a texture region won't help to decrease memoryconsumption, instead you would only increase the cutout/clipping you see from your atlas

e.g., let your image look like this (with texture regions A, B, C, D):

AB

CD

doubling the width and height of your texture region would result in one large texture region containing the textures of A B C and D (and that is probably not what you want)

if your platforms consist of only one texture region A, you can load that as a single png into a new atlas and add `TextureOptions.REPEATING_NEARIST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA` in the constructor. then you can set the width and height of the texture region to the desired width and height of your sprite and the atlas will repeat it - it will be drawn AAAAA if you use

```
textureRegionHeight = imageHeight; 
textureRegionWidth = 5* imageWidth;
spriteWidth = textureRegionHeight;
spriteHeight = textureRegionHeight;
```

**additional information**

to improve the performance, you should work with:

- Sprite pooling (more: object pooling in general) (you can never show more than 100 32x32 sprites next to each other, since some of them would be out of the screen soon)
- SpriteBatch for unchangeable/static same Sprites, SpriteGroup for others (as soon as you know there  could be more than 5 to 10 sprites with the same texture, i never measured if these groups are better or worse than the REPEATING_NEAREST option)
- Sprite.setCullingEnabled(true) for each sprite object, since it will stop drawing sprites that are not visible/outside of the screen (i neither measured if culling works well with REPEATING_NEAREST)

these points should improve the performance

further information could be found at http://www.matim-dev.com/tips-and-tricks---how-to-improve-performance.html or in the AndEngine forum at http://www.andengine.org/forums/search.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I decided to change from Andengine to Libgdx when I got artefacts when repeating textures. No one could help me on the Andengine forum and I was sick of always getting strange results with textures. But concerning the problem I posted here, I decided to create each platform with 9 sprites with this layout :
0111112 \n

3444445 \n

3444445 \n

3444445 \n

6777778

Comment: with artifacts, you mean like thin black lines at the border of your sprites? that's a common problem with some more or less working solutions (e.g. [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/black-lines-around-sprites-t5255.html) - what helped me the most, was to use the TextureOptions.REPEATING_NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA and a single atlas for each sprite :-/

Comment: the layout you posted would be an ideal usecase for the repeating_nearest with an explicit atlas for 1, 3, 4, 5 and 7 (and each have their own 32x32 png.

Comment: and the black stripes are only on your corners and you tried it with a transparent 1px line on your tiled? in one game, i solved the problem with `new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), width, height,BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888,TextureOptions.REPEATING_BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);` - then i loaded all(except those that should use NEAREST) textures needed to the atlas (each from a single png), adding a 1px line between each. it's a little bit more loading time, but got rid of the black lines

Comment: I think it corrected my artefact problems, but there seems to be 1px spaces between my sprites sometimes when the camera moves, and when it stops, sometimes the spaces disapear and sometimes they appear between other sprites. Note that those spaces aren't seen on every platforms, but every platform is created the same way. Maybe the scene have difficulty drawing multiple sprites at their exact place?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33166/discussion-between-christian-r-and-racingracist)